# why are "feet" common and "chemistry" abstract nouns?

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns

why are **feet** common and **chemistry** abstract nouns?

Why feet is considered as common noun?

why chemistry is considered as abstract noun?

Comment: 'feet' is a 'count noun'. 'chemistry' an abstract noun because a noun denoting an idea, quality, or state **rather than a concrete object** is abstract noun.

Comment: Ever touched "chemistry"? And "feet"? That's the difference.

Comment: @Stephie Feet can act as both abstract and common noun.1)  Length in feet which is an abstract noun.2) feet of a living being where it is a common noun.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, a common noun is any noun that isn't a (proper) name.

What you are probably talking about are **concrete** nouns, or nouns that refer to things directly sensed by any of your five senses (see, touch, smell, taste, hear).

e.g.

> fire, music, guns, computer, kitten, chair, nuclear warheads, oxen, cows, meat, wood, car, street, mirrors, light

**Abstract** nouns are nouns that are not directly felt by the five senses.

e.g.

> society, bravery, awesomeness, anger, mathematics, concept, time, mentality, definition, programming, self-worth

Feet can be seen (at the bottom of the human body) or touched, so it is a concrete noun.

You can't directly touch chemistry, or taste chemistry, or directly see chemistry, or smell chemistry, or hear chemistry, so it is an abstract noun.